# function executing only the first statement (if) and not the second one (else if)

Tags: javascript

My code executes only the if statement (`memefontsize`) and forgets to execute the `memefontsize2`. If u need more information regarding my code let me know.

```
layer.add(scriptolutiondotcomtop2);
layer.draw();
var textscriptolutionheight2 = stage.getHeight();
layer.draw();


layer.add(scriptolutiondotcomtop);
layer.draw();
var textscriptolutionheight = stage.getHeight();
layer.draw();

function lowertopsize() {
  if (memefontsize > 10) {

    memefontsize = memefontsize - 1;
    memedotcomtop.fontSize(memefontsize);
    layer.draw()

  } else if (memefontsize2 > 10) {

    memefontsize2 = memefontsize2 - 1;
    memedotcomtop2.fontSize(memefontsize2);
    layer.draw();
  }
}
```

Comment: `memefontsize` has not been defined. Do you see any console log errors ?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean.  How does it "forget to execute"?  When you step through this in a debugger, where specifically is it failing?  What are the runtime values when that happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`else` or `else if` only execute when `if` condition is not satisfied.

If you wanna check both `memefontsize` and `memefontsize2` you have to provide `if` instead of `if..else`

Try like this

```
if (memefontsize > 10) {

  memefontsize = memefontsize - 1;
  memedotcomtop.fontSize(memefontsize);
  layer.draw()

}
if (memefontsize2 > 10) {

  memefontsize2 = memefontsize2 - 1;
  memedotcomtop2.fontSize(memefontsize2);
  layer.draw();

}
```

Comment: okay you are absolutely right. However, the point of this function to decrease the size of the font separately and not for both at the same time. any idea? @Anik Islam Abhi

Comment: `memedotcomtop` and `memedotcomtop2` are different when do you wanna to change ?